# Are integers mod n a unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to learn abstract algebra from scratch, jolly stuff, but in the process of doing so this puzzles me:

Having a ring of integers mod $n$, where $n=pq$ is composite, as I understand we have that  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a Principal Ideal Domain (PID) (by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42076/on-proving-every-ideal-of-mathbbz-n-is-principal)). Therefore by the pretty chain of inclusions located [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), it is also a unique factorization domain.

And this is where I am lost, as I keep thinking of for example $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ where I can have $4\equiv 2\cdot2 \equiv 2\cdot2\cdot5 \bmod 8$. Also, $p\cdot q \equiv 0 \bmod n$ which gives two non-zero divisors of zero. In my world, this means that $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ is not a UFD and not even integral domain.

I feel like I am missing something very simple yet crucial :-).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the question to which you linked. What is asserted there is that all ideals of $\mathbb Z/n$ are principal.  But that does not make $\mathbb Z/n$ a PID unless it is an integral domain, and, as Bill Dubuque said, that happens only when $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 16):

When $\,n\,$ is composite $\,\Bbb Z/n\,$ is not an integral domain. Factorization theory is much more complicated in non-domains, e.g. $\rm\:x = (3+2x)(2-3x)\in \Bbb Z_6[x].\:$ Basic notions such as *associate* and *irreducible* bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions, e.g. see

[When are Associates Unit Multiples?](http://doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181069828)
D.D. Anderson, M. Axtell, S.J. Forman, and Joe Stickles.
Rocky Mountain J. Math. Volume 34, Number 3 (2004), 811-828.

[Factorization in Commutative Rings with Zero-divisors.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181072068)
D.D. Anderson, Silvia Valdes-Leon.
Rocky Mountain J. Math. Volume 28, Number 2 (1996), 439-480

Comment: Bill, it is known that if in $A$ irreducibles are primes, then the product of primitive polynomials in $A[X]$ is primitive. Can we weaken this condition? If you could drop by the chat, it'd be better.

Comment: @Pedro See D.D. Anderson: *GCD domains, Gauss' lemma, and contents of polynomials*, 2000, for a superb survey on this and related topics.

Comment: See also this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101989/divisibility-and-factorization-in-rings-that-are-not-integral-domains).