# Irreducible elements for a commutative ring that is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Why does the definition of an irreducible element require us to be in an integral domain?
>   Why can we not define an irreducible element exactly the same in a commutative ring that is not an integral domain?

We have that an element is irreducible if it cannot be written as a product of two non-unit elements. Unit elements are well defined and unique in a commutative ring that is not an integral domain, so I cannot see that being the problem.

I've proven a proposition of my own design (probably well known and elementary, an definitely trivial). I used irreducible elements, but otherwise nothing that requires me to move from a commutative ring to an integral domain. Do irreducible elements really require me to be in an integral domain?

Comment: The notion makes sense over any commutative ring with unity. But note that some well known results get false if the ring has zero-divisors. For example a non-trivial idempotent is never irreducible, but might be prime.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/242) and the linked papers for a starting point on factorization theory in rings with zero-divisors.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In an integral domain, you have the following four equivalent definitions for a nonzero nonunit $a$ to be irreducible.

1. $a = bc \Rightarrow (a) = (b)$ or $(a) = (c)$.
2. $a = bc \Rightarrow a$ is a unit multiple of $b$ or $c$.
3. $(a)$ is maximal among the proper principal ideals.
4. $a = bc \Rightarrow b$ or $c$ is a unit.

However, in commutative rings in general, we have (4) $\Rightarrow$ (3) $\Rightarrow$ (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1), and none of the implications reverse.  The literature for factorization in commutative rings with zero divisors thus has four different non-equivalent definitions of "irreducible".  (The above statements define "irreducible", "strongly irreducible", "m-irreducible", and "very strongly irreducible", respectively.)  See [Factorization in Commutative Rings with Zero Divisors](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181072068) by Anderson and Valdes-Leon for more information.

Comment: fyi: That is one of the papers linked in the comment I gave above. Both are open access so can be freely downloaded.

Comment: This is very very cool. Thanks very much!