# non-uniqueness of factorization in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring

I just finished a unit on the uniqueness of factorization in $F[x]$, but my textbook didn't give me an example of non-uniqueness in $R[x]$ where $R$ isn't a field.  Is there a simple example of a polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}[x]$ (or some other non-field) that has multiple factorizations into irreducibles? In other words, I know why the proof depends on $F$ being a field, I just would like to see an example showing why uniqueness doesn't work in $R[x]$.  Thanks!

Comment: Does the notion of irreducible still make sense for rings that are not domains? See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838066/irreducible-elements-for-a-commutative-ring-that-is-not-an-integral-domain/1838593

Comment: In the context of polynomial rings it seems like it still makes sense, but I don't really know.  My book says that f(x) is reducible if it can be written as a product of two polynomials of lesser degree, so in this context the definition is stronger than just being written as a product of two non-units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with
$$(x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1=x^2-25=(x-5)(x+5).$$

Comment: Zero divisors at play here. The product $(x-1)(x+1)$ vanishes at $x=5$ even though neither of the factors does.

Comment: But is it clear that the linear factors are irreducible? They may be the product of two quadratic polynomials for instance.

Comment: A good question @lhf! I don't have time to think about it now. I'm needed elsewhere in five.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $x+1=(6x+1)(6x^2+7x+1)$

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even if the linear factors can be written as products of quadratics, this example works for the definition in my book (Fraleigh).  Fraleigh counts all linear polynomials as irreducible.

Comment: @JoseBrox That is an interesting fact. But because $6$ is nilpotent in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ your other factor $6x+1$ is of the form $1+n$ with $n$ nilpotent. Therefore it is a unit in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{12}[x]$. This means that your factorization does not make $x+1$ reducible. To wit, $(1+6x)^2=1$.

Comment: I don't think I can shed enough light on the "proper" way of defining irreducible elements in a ring with zero divisors. The interested readers can use [Bill Dubuque's old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/11619) and the links in there to learn more.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right. That was fun! Next I would play $x+1=(4x+1)(1-3x)$, but now I'm not sure whether the factors are units or not! A straightforward proof does not come to mind, although they are not inverted by linear polynomials.

Comment: And, @JoseBrox, your second factorization [does not seem to have units](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19132/11619). I'm at loss here :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the result on units of $R[X]$! About the "unfortunate sequence of events", I thought that maybe was something public. Never mind.