# unique factorization in polynomial modulo $p^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

I read such a judgement,it says:

> If $p$ is a prime integer,then the non-constant polynomials in $\mathbb Z/(p^k)[x]$ have a unique factorization, for positive integer $k$.

So how can I prove it? since  $\mathbb Z(p^k)$ is not a field.

Comment: You have to be careful with the definitions. For example, when $p=k=2$ we have factorizations like
$$(x+2)^2=x^2+4x+4\equiv x^2\pmod4.$$
So uniqueness is violated unless the factorizations $(x+2)^2$ and $x^2$ are somehow the same.

Comment: See [Bill Dubuque's old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/11619) for more information and links. I guess [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2511040/11619) is related, too.

Comment: You are right,my judgement should be fake.

Answer (score 4):

$F_{p^k}$ is not the same thing as $Z/(p^k)$ because the former is a field with $p^k$ elements, whereas the latter is just a ring with $p^k$ elements (and not a field when $k>1$).

For instance, if $p^k = 2^2 = 4$ then $F_4$ is a field with 4 elements {0,1,a,b} in which $x+x = 0$ for all $x \in F_4$.  However, $Z/(4)$ is a ring with 4 elements {0,1,2,3}, and in this ring, 1+1 is not 0.

Comment: oh,sorry.i believe it is the Z/(pk) case

Comment: But now that you replaced $F_{p^k}$ by $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)$,  this $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)[x]$ can not be a UFD for $k>1$ because it fails the "D" part of UFD.  For $k>1$ this is not an integral Domain.

Comment: alright,thank you!