# Defining irreducible polynomials over polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, polynomial-rings

Let R be a ring, and R[x] be a polynomial ring.

Can we define what it means for a polynomial $p(x) \in R[x]$ to be irreducible over R[x]?

Various sources (such as [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#Definition)) only provide such definition for a field or a unique factorization domain.

Comment: The definition that cleanly generalizes is the notion of prime element, which just means that $(p(x))$ is a prime ideal. Irreducibility is trickier and probably there is no notion which has all the properties you expect, so you need to pick which ones to give up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what *irreducible* means in rings that are not domains.

You can define *irreducible* but it won't have all properties you expect. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1838593/589).

In particular, if $R$ is not a domain, it may happen that decomposing a polynomial in $R[x]$ does not simplify it (that is, does not reduce its degree).

For instance:
$$
5x+1=(2x+1)(3x+1) \bmod 6
$$

It is even possible to decompose a linear polynomial as a product of two *quadratic* polynomials:
$$
x+1=(2x^2+x+7)(4x^2+6x+7) \bmod 8
$$

Comment: Thanks for the very insightful answer. I just need to ask one more thing: Your answer completely explains why R should be a domain, and the link you provided discussed why R should be an integral domain. I still don't get why R should be a UFD, as per Wikipedia definition?

Comment: @M.S.Dousti, if $R$ is a domain, $R[x]$ is a subring of $K[x]$, which is a UFD. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Wikipedia definition requires R (the underlying ring) to be a UFD, while you are saying that if R is a domain, then R[x] (the polynomial ring itself) is a UFD. So, I think the definition in Wikipedia is much more strict.

Comment: @M.S.Dousti, I meant, $K[x]$ is a UFD.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69538/242) for links to literature on factroization in rings with zero divisors.

Answer (score 3):

When I taught abstract algebra, I pointed out that any commutative ring with multiplicative unit could be split up into disjoint sets:
\begin{align}
1.&\quad\{0\}\\
2.&\quad\text{nonzero zero-divisors (including nilpotent elements)}\\
3.&\quad\text{units}\\
4.&\quad\text{decomposable elements: those writable as}\\
&\quad\text{product two elements not in classes 1, 2, 3}\\
5.&\quad\text{everything else.}
\end{align}
The indecomposable elements, also called irreducibles, are those in class 5.

So, for $a$ to be irreducible would mean that $a$ was not writable as product of two non-unit non-zero-divisors, and my “irreducibles” would be the “strong irreducibles” in the categorization mentioned in the link offered by @lhf.