# Are all polynomials of degree 1 irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Suppose we define an irreducible polynomial in the following way:

Let $P(X) \in \{K[x] \text{ of degree at least 1}\}$. $P(x)$ is irreducible over the ring $K$ iif:
$$
\forall A(x), B(x)\in K[x]:A(x)B(x) = P(x) \implies (\text{deg}(A)=0 \text{ } \lor \text{deg(B)}=0)
$$

Now consider the following test question:

Every polynomial of degree 1 from $K[x]$ is irreducible. Is this statement true or false?

Comment: $K$ is a ring, not a field (as the letter would suggest)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't know what the $K$ stands for, but it is indeed a ring.

Comment: I would have $R$ or $A$ for a ring, whereas $K$ (and $F$, of course) is often used for fields. While $F$ for fields is obvious, the use of $K$ seems to origin form the German word "Körper".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you, "Körper" explains a lot. I just realized that since I translated the definition from Czech, where the word "kruh" means "circle", and "okruh" means "ring", the $K$ is for the Czech okruh.

Comment: @Josef That may be a coincidence.  "Körper" does not mean "field" or "ring" in German, it means "body".  It just happens that they chose a different name for the same algebraic structure.  These names are fairly arbitrary in most languages, the algebraic structure does not much resemble the day to day meaning of field or body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The claim is true if $K$ is a field or at least an integral domain.
For general rings $K$, however, the claim is false.

By a suitable choice of $K$, we can find a degree 1 polynomial $P(x)$ that is the product of degree 1 polynomials $A(x)=3x+1$ and $B(x)=2x+1$, for example. You may object that this would make $A(x)B(x)=6x^2+5x+1$ of degree $>1$. But not so if $K=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! By the way, your the $6x$ in your equation is missing an exponent.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2539517/589 for a linear polynomial that decomposes as a product of two quadratic polynomials

Comment: @Josef Thanks, fixed

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the definition in the question is (to my knowledge) not the standard definition of an irreducible polynomial. The usual definition requires the stronger condition that $A$ or $B$ is a unit in $K[X]$ and hence a unit in $K$ (which implies that the degree is $0$). However, when using this definition, the result only holds when every non-zero element in $K$ is a unit i.e. when $K$ is a field