# The role of coefficients in dividable a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, modules

Let $m$ and $p$, be two positive integer numbers. Consider the following polynomial 
$$
f(x)=x^p-u_{p-1}\,x^{p-1}-u_{p-2}\, x^{p-2}-\cdots-u_1\, x-u_0
$$
Suppose the coefficient $u_0$, is **relatively prime** to $m$.
 Consider $a$ and $b$, be two positive integer numbers such that $a<b$.  My question it is, 
If the polynomial $f(x)$, divides the polynomials $x^a(x^b-1)$ over modulo $m$, why we can conclude that 
the polynomial $f(x)$, divides the polynomial $(x^b-1)$ over modulo $m$ and not the polynomial $x^a$. In other words, I
want to say
$$
 f(x)\mid x^a(x^b-1) \mod{m} \quad \Rightarrow  \quad  f(x)\mid (x^b-1) \mod{m} \quad \& \quad  f(x)\nmid x^a \mod{m}
$$
 I would greatly appreciate for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows immediately by Euclid's Lemma, i.e.

$$ \color{#c00}{(f,x)= 1},\ f\mid x^ag\,\Rightarrow\, f\mid x^a g, fg\,\Rightarrow\, f\mid (x^ag,fg) = (\color{#c00}{x^a,f})g = g$$

In your case $\,(x,f) = (x,u_0) = (1)\,$  since $\,(u_0) = 1\, $ in $ \,\Bbb Z_m[x]\,$

Comment: $u_0$ is coprime to $m$ and because of this there is inverse of $u_0$ over modulo $m$. So, $x=u_0\, (u_0^{-1}\,x)$ or $u_0\mid x$ over $m$, and it means $(x,u_0)\neq 1$ over modulo $m$. In fact, if we mention that the value of $p$ is at least $1$, then we can conclude that $f(x)$ is coprime to $x$, because of $u_0$ and after that it results that $f(x)$ is coprime to $x^a$ and after that by using Euclid's Lemma we get $f(x)$ divides $(x^b-1)$. Is it true discussion? Thanks again for your hint about Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: @Amin235 $\ u_0 $ is a unit (invertible) mod $\,m.\,$ In general domains gcds are define only up to unit factors, so a unit gcd is the same as gcd $= 1.$ Beware that if $\,m\,$ is not prime then $\,\Bbb Z_m\,$ is not a domain (has zero-divisors) so [divisibility theory becomes more complicated.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/242)  Yes, that paraphrases  the argument.

Comment: @Amin235 Btw, if ideal language is not familiar then you can write out the above proof explicitly using Bezout linear combinations for the gcds $(= 1),\,$ just like in the integer case.

Comment: Thanks for your useful hint.

Answer (score 0):

We proof by contradiction or reductio ad absurdum method. Suppose that  $f(x)$ dose not divide $(x^b-1)$, which results 
that $f(x)$ should divides $x^a$ over mod $m$. So, we conclude that there is a polynomial of degree $a-p$,
 like $v(x)$, in the following form

$$
 v(x) \, b(x)=x^a \qquad \mod{m}
 $$
 $$
 (x^{a-p}-v_{a-p-1}\,x^{a-p-1}-\cdots-v_1\, x-v_0)
  (x^p-u_{p-1}\,x^{p-1}-u_{p-2}\, x^{p-2}-\cdots-u_1\, x-u_0)=x^a \, \mod{m}
 $$
 From the above equation, we conclude that $ v_0\, u_0\mid m$. In addition, 
 by assumption $(u_0,m)=1$,  which results that $v_0=0$ over modulo $m$. So, we have
  $$
 (x^{a-p-1}-v_{a-p-1}\,x^{a-p-2}-\cdots-v_2\, x-v_1)
  (x^p-u_{p-1}\,x^{p-1}-u_{p-2}\, x^{p-2}-\cdots-u_1\, x-u_0)=x^{a-1} \, \mod{m}
 $$
But it is not true that $f(x)$ divides two consecutive power of $x$, except when $f(x)$ be power of $x$ and it is contradiction to assumption that $a_0$ is coprome to modulo $m$. Is it true discussion or not. Tanks again