# Using of the Least common multiple in the modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules, least-common-multiple

Suppose $n=p_1^{e_1}\,p_2^{e_2}\, \cdots \, p_t^{e_t}$ where $p_i$,$1\leq i \leq t$, are prime numbers and $P(X) \in \mathbb Z_d[X]$.
 Now, my question it is,   If $X^{q_i} - 1$, is divisible
 by $P(X)$ mod $p_i^{e_i}$,$1\leq i \leq t$,where $q_i$ are positive integer numbers, and $Lcm(q_1\,q_2\, \cdots, \, q_t)$ be a number 
like $m$ where $Lcm$ is the Least common multiple, then can we conclude that $X^{m}-1$ is divisible by $P(X)$ mod $n$?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem. The ideals $\,I_i = (P,p_i^e)\,$ are pairwise coprime (i.e. comaximal) since the $\,(p^{\large e_i})\,$ are.

${\rm mod}\ I_i:\,\ \color{#c00}{X^{\large q_i}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow X^m \equiv (\color{#c00}{X^{\large q_i}})^{\large m/q_i}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{\large m/q_i}\equiv 1$

Thus $\,X^m\!-1\in I_i\,\Rightarrow\, X^m\!-1\in \bigcap I_i.\,$ But $\,\bigcap I_i =  \prod I_i\, $ by $\,I_i\,$ pairwise coprime.

Note $\,\color{#0a0}{A+B=1}\,\Rightarrow\, (P,A)(P,B) = (P(P,\color{#0a0}{A,B}),AB) = (P,AB)\ $ thus we infer by induction that $\ \prod I_i = (P,\, p_1^{\large e_1}\cdots p_t^{\large e_t})$

We essentially  employed the *uniqueness* of the CRT solution $\,Y = X^m\,$  of $\, Y\equiv 1 \pmod{I_i}.\,$ This is the ideal-theoretic analog of the integer *constant-case* CRT that I [described here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242)

Comment: I appreciate your answering my question and I would be grateful if you could help me for my previous [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018558/the-role-of-coefficients-in-dividable-a-polynomial/2018900#2018900). Thanks again