# What is an irreducible element in $\Bbb{Z}_6[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, factoring

> What is an irreducible element in $\Bbb{Z}_6[x]$?

This was a problem on our final and no one knew how to solve it. Does anyone have a method for solving this?

Comment: Is the question asking for a definition or an example?

Comment: An example with proof @PeterTaylor

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, $x$ is reducible here: $x=(2x+3)(3x+2)$.  Even $2$ is not reducible: $2=2\cdot 4$.  The same goes for $3$: $3=3\cdot 3$.

Comment: Factorization of polynomials (and consequently also irreducibility) becomes rather delicate when the modulus is not a power of a prime. I have been linking several questions of this type to [this answer by Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732004/11619) where more material can be found. For more incarnations of this theme on our site see the several questions linked to that.

Comment: Modulo a prime power the theory is quite a bit simpler. Even though we still have zero divisors and intricacies like $x^2\equiv(x-2)^2\pmod 4$. In the prime power case the subset of polynomials with zeros that are roots of unity of order prime to $p$ behave reasonably well (because Hensel lifting), and give rise to a theory of Galois rings extending some of the facts from the theory of finite fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Claim.** Assume that $\Bbb Z_m=\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$.  The polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb Z_6[x]$ is irreducible if and only if exactly one of these is true:
>   $(a)$ $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_2$ and $f(x)\equiv \pm1\pmod{3}$ or
>   $(b)$ $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_3$ and $f(x)\equiv 1\pmod{2}$.

Suppose that $f(x)\in \Bbb Z_6[x]$ is irreducible.  Then, $f(x)$ is either irreducible or invertible over $\Bbb{Z}_2$, and over $\Bbb{Z}_3$.  If $f(x)$ is invertible in both $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$, then $f(x)$ is one of the constant polynomials $\pm1$, which are invertible (and not irreducible).  This is a contradiction, so $f(x)$ must either be irreducible over $\Bbb Z_2$ or over $\Bbb Z_3$.

If $f(x)$ is invertible in neither $\Bbb Z_2$ nor $\Bbb Z_3$, then we can solve for $$u(x)\equiv 1\pmod{2}\ \ \  \wedge\ \ \  u(x)\equiv f(x)\pmod 3$$
and
$$v(x)\equiv f(x)\pmod{2}\ \ \ \wedge \ \ \ v(x)\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$
for $u(x),v(x)\in\Bbb{Z}_6[x]$.  These $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are non-invertible over $\Bbb Z_6$ (since $u(x)$ is non-invertible modulo $3$, and $v(x)$ is non-invertible modulo $2$).  However, $f(x)=u(x)\cdot v(x)$ in $\Bbb Z_6[x]$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore, either $(a)$ or $(b)$ holds, but not both.

Conversely, suppose that $(a)$ holds.  If $f(x)=p(x)\cdot q(x)$ for some $p(x),q(x)\in \Bbb Z_6[x]$, then reduce $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ modulo $2$ and $3$ respectively.  As $f(x)$ is irreducible mod $2$, $(p,q)=(f,1)$ or $(p,q)=(1,f)$ modulo $2$.  Wlog, $p=f$ and $q=1$.   As $f(x)\equiv \pm 1\pmod{3}$, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ modulo $3$ are constants $\pm 1$.  Thus, $q(x)\equiv 1\pmod{2}$ and $q(x)\equiv -1\pmod{3}$. Therefore, $q(x)= \pm 1$ in $\Bbb Z_6[x]$.  That is, $q(x)$ is constant, and so $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Finally, suppose that $(b)$ holds.  If $f(x)=p(x)\cdot q(x)$ for some $p(x),q(x)\in \Bbb Z_6[x]$, then reduce $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ modulo $2$ and $3$ respectively.  As $f(x)$ is irreducible mod $3$, $(p,q)=(f,1)$ or $(p,q)=(1,f)$ modulo $3$, up to sign swapping.  Wlog, $p=f$ and $q=1$.   As $f(x)\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ modulo $2$ equal the constant $1$.  Thus, $q(x)\equiv 1\pmod{2}$. Therefore, $q(x)= 1$ in $\Bbb Z_6[x]$.  That is, $q(x)$ is constant, and so $f(x)$ is irreducible.

**Examples.**  The polynomial $f(x)=3x+1$ fits $(a)$, so it is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_6[x]$.   The polynomial $f(x)=2x+1$ fits $(b)$, so it is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_6[x]$.