# Minimum number of terms resulting from the product of two polynomials with a given number of terms

Tags: polynomials

Given two integers ($n$, $m$), what is the smallest number of terms that could result from the product of two polynomials with $n$ and $m$ non-zero terms respectively?

That is, what is the smallest number of non-zero terms that could result from the following product:

$$(a_1 x^{b_1} + \dots + a_n x ^ {b_n})(c_1 x^{d_1} + \dots + c_m x ^ {d_m})$$

where $a_i$ and $c_i$ are non-zero.

The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3376/206542) show that the answer cannot be $1$ in all cases, but it is obviously less than $n+m$, which should theoretically be the maximum.

Comment: What do you mean by "represent the size"? This is rather ambiguous, but I assume that $m$ and $n$ are, respectively, the number of terms of those two polynomials. Is this correct? It would also help to know where the coefficients come from. For example, are they integer, real, or complex?

Comment: @AP Yes, sorry, $m$ and $n$ are the number of terms in the polynomials.

Comment: Are you only counting nonzero terms? Are we dealing with real polynomials, or polynomials over a field, or what exactly?

Comment: @SE318 Yes, only non-zero terms.  I don't have a specific criteria for the coefficients, though so far I've thought of them as being integers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(x - 1)(x^n+ \dotsb + 1) = x^{n+1} -1$

Comment: This shows that for cases of the form $(2, n)$ the answer is $2$, but I'm not sure I see how this leads to a more general solution?  I could see this maybe being expanding to handle even cases, by treating the first polynomial as the product of $(x-1)$ and the complement of the prior result (i.e. $x^{n+1} + 1$), so I could see $(2k, n) \rightarrow 2$ but I'm not even sure that would necessarily hold for all $n$.

Comment: @thesquaregroot, I believe the cyclotomic polynomials (i.e., factors of $x^n - 1$) provide examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proof that this is best possible in mind, but I believe for $m,n>1$, $\min{(m,n)}$ can be done using a technique similar to vonbrand's answer using a generalized idea of Fibonacci numbers, the Fibonacci n step numbers: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html

For (m,n) with $1<m\leq n$, consider $$(x^{m-1}+x^{m-2}+...+x-1)(f_0+f_1x+f_2x^2+...+f_{n-1}x^{n-1})$$ where $f_i$ is the $i$th Fibonacci $n-1$ step number. The Fibonacci recurrence relation guarantees that all the terms except the constant term and the $m-1$ terms of degree $n+m-2$ through $n$ cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum is 2 for all cases. For even number of terms, there is an elegant factorization solution, but for odd number of terms, my solution made use of complex roots.

Let $A$ have $a$ terms, $B$ have $b$ terms.  $C=A\cdot B$.

We prove that for any $a,b\geq2$, we can always find $A,B$ so that $C$ has $2$ terms, which is obviously the minimum.

1. $a$ or $b$ (or both) is even: assume $b$ is even.  \begin{align*}
   x^{\frac{ab}{2}}-1&=(x^a-1)\left[(x^a)^{\frac{b}{2}-1}+(x^a)^{\frac{b}{2}-2}+\dots+1\right] \\
   &=(x^{a-1}+x^{a-2}+\dots+1)(x-1)\left[(x^a)^{\frac{b}{2}-1}+(x^a)^{\frac{b}{2}-2}+\dots+1\right]
   \end{align*} Let $A=x^{a-1}+x^{a-2}+\dots+1$, $B=(x-1)\left[(x^a)^{\frac{b}{2}-1}+(x^a)^{\frac{b}{2}-2}+\dots+1\right]$.  It's easy to check that $B$ has $b$ terms, since no terms in the expansion will cancel out.
2. Both $a$ and $b$ odd: (I did not find a similar proof like (1), so I used complex roots.)  We demonstrate with the example $a=3,b=7$.  The general case only substitutes numbers as $a$s and $b$s.

   We wish to construct $A$ to have $2$ roots and $B$ to have $b$ roots.  Plot the $8$ complex number solutions of $x^8+1=0$ on the unit circle.  Name them $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_8$.

   Because $a,b$ is odd, $z_5=\overline{z_4},z_6=\overline{z_3},\dots,z_8=\overline{z_1}$  Let \begin{gather*}
   A=(x-\mathcal{E}_1)(x-\overline{\mathcal{E}_1}) \\
   B=(x-\mathcal{E}_2)(x-\overline{\mathcal{E}_2})(x-\mathcal{E}_3)(x-\overline{\mathcal{E}_3})(x-\mathcal{E}_4)(x-\overline{\mathcal{E}_4})
   \end{gather*}  It's easy to check that both $A$ and $B$ have non-zero co-efficients.

---

Note: the complex number solution can yield elementary factorization solutions for $a=3,b=3$.  \begin{gather*}
\underbrace{x^4+4}_\text{2 terms}=(\underbrace{x^2+2x+2}_\text{3 terms})(\underbrace{x^2-2x+2}_\text{3 terms})\tag{*} \\
A=\left((x-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i\right)\right)\left(x-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i\right)\right)=x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1
\end{gather*}  Similarly, we calculuate $$B=x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1$$  So $$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)$$  Let $x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}t$ and we'd get: $$\frac{t^4}{4}+1=\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+t+1\right)\left(\frac{t^2}{2}-t+1\right)$$ which is exactly (*).

For a handwritten version of this answer with diagrams, see photo [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FQqw.jpg).

Comment: You should type answer using mathjax instead of image.

Comment: @DoraYuan: I've typed up your image using MathJax.  Using the "edit" link (in gray, below your answer), you can see how I did this (for next time) and correct any errors I've made.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, by the way!

Comment: $(x^2+3x+3)(x^4-3x^3+6x^2-9x+9)=x^6+27$.