# For a given polynomial, what is the multiple with the fewest terms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I wonder if you can solve the following problem in general: Let $f$ be a polynomial in $K[x]$, where $K$ is a field. Find a polynomial $g$ such that $fg$ has minimal number of terms (not zero).

If you restrict the maximum possible degree of $g$, you can solve the problem easily (although with a lot of computational effort, if I see it correctly).

What can be said for arbitrary multiples? Can one somehow restrict the degree of a shortest multiple by the degree and the size of the coefficients of $f$?

If anyone knows more about this, I would be very happy.

(The question has a connection to the following thread: [Minimum number of terms resulting from the product of two polynomials with a given number of terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604933/minimum-number-of-terms-resulting-from-the-product-of-two-polynomials-with-a-giv?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42869/242) shows how to test if a polynomial has a multiple of form $x^n-1$, i.e. ìs cyclotomic

Comment: See [Computing sparse multiples of polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3214) by Mark Giesbrecht, Daniel S. Roche, Hrushikesh Tilak.